# I am unable to add Data Field to my Pivot Table VBA

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I get a runtime error

> Unable to get the PivotTables property of Worksheet class

when I run the following code:

```
Sub UpdatePivot()

Dim ws As Worksheet, SrcData As String, pvtCache As PivotCache
Dim ws2 As Worksheet, NR As Long, NC As Long, ws3 As Worksheet
Dim pf As PivotField, pt As PivotTable, df As PivotField, str As String

'Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Lisun Data")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Cover")
Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Stockist")
Set pt = ws3.PivotTables("PivotTable3")
Set pt = ws3.PivotTables("PivotTable3")
With pt.PivotFields(" May-17")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Function = xlSum
    .Position = 1
End With

End Sub
```

May I know what is wrong?

I did add the data source to a data model beforehand, and I'm not sure what exactly is causing the error.

Comment: Ensure you are referring to correct sheet and the pivot table name exists on that sheet

Comment: Turn the macro recorder on, and manually perform the action you are trying to do, so that you can then look at the code that is generated, and so see what changes you need to make to the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below to try and trap your errors, explanations inside the code's comments:

```
Option Explicit

Sub UpdatePivot()

Dim ws As Worksheet, SrcData As String, pvtCache As PivotCache
Dim ws2 As Worksheet, NR As Long, NC As Long, ws3 As Worksheet
Dim pf As PivotField, pt As PivotTable, df As PivotField, str As String

'Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Lisun Data")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Cover")
Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Stockist")

' 1ST: Trap the Pivot-Table object
On Error Resume Next
Set pt = ws3.PivotTables("PivotTable3")
On Error GoTo 0
If pt Is Nothing Then '<-- Pivot Table does't exist (Pivot Table renamed ?)
    MsgBox "Pivot-Table object Error!"
Else ' Pivot-Table object exists

    ' 2NDT: Trap the PivotField object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set pf = pt.PivotFields(" May-17")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If pf Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Pivot-Field object Error!"
    Else
        With pf
            .Orientation = xlColumnField
            .Function = xlSum
            .Position = 1
        End With
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I know what's the problem now but I still don;t know how to solve it. The problem is that I am calling the Pivot Field from the data model, which means that the Pivot Field name is [Table3].[May-17].[May-17], something like that. However, I tried replacing the Pivot Field name with that and it still doesn't work. How do I add data model fields to rows or columns? Anyone knows? I've been on this for 2 days now.

Comment: @Nanth you want to add it ? it doesn;t exists already in the Pivot-Table ?

Comment: It exists as a Pivot Field and I want to drag it to the row area using VBA.

Comment: @Nanth not clear to me, according to your code you want to have a "sum" of it, but you mention you want it in the Row area, so which on is it ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @Shai Rado for all your feedback, extremely valuable. Also big big thanks to @jeffreyweir, I recorded a macro and found out the answer that I needed. The code for adding any pivot field from a data model is below:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable3").CubeFields("[Measures].[Sum of May-17]"), "Sum of May-17"
```